# language issue in TeeChart

Tags: windows, visual-c++, teechart

During using Teechart active X, the language of Teechart Edit Dialog is changed to japanese or chinese.(don't know exactly what language)

How can I recover to English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At design time, open the contextual menu (right click on the chart). The "Language" option is the second from the bottom:

[image: Language]

Then, in the next screen, "English" is the first item in the list:

[image: English]

Close and restart the IDE to apply the changes on the contextual menu.